# How to avoid adding JARs on the Hazelcast server classpath for the serialization to work?

Tags: serialization, hazelcast

We have a spring mvc based web app that is running with JDK 8 and Spring version 5.3.29. Working on trying to store the http session in the Hazelcast distributed map store. Started with testing the first approach of using the following dependencies and using the com.hazelcast.web.spring.SpringAwareWebFilter implemented it. The objects that the web app stores on the session, implement Java serializable interface and are stored properly in the hazelcast map. With 2 instances of a hazelcast server running the web app uses a hazelcast client xml configuration to help them connect with those hazelcast servers and it worked out all well.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-wm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

But I realized that with this implementation it's tightly coupled with the Hazelcast. so we started trying the following approach of spring-session-hazelcast which can be replaced with other implementations like Redis if required.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This worked out as well with needing to add the following change -

```
@Configuration
@EnableHazelcastHttpSession
public class SessionConfiguration {

    private final String SESSIONS_MAP_NAME = "uob-sam-sessions";

    @Bean
    public SessionRepositoryCustomizer<Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository> customize() {
        
        return (sessionRepository) -> {
            sessionRepository.setFlushMode(FlushMode.IMMEDIATE);
            sessionRepository.setSaveMode(SaveMode.ALWAYS);
            sessionRepository.setSessionMapName(SESSIONS_MAP_NAME);
            sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(900);
        };
    }   
    
    @Bean
    @SpringSessionHazelcastInstance
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.setClusterName("dev");
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1:5701");
        clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress("127.0.0.1:5702");
        
        return HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(clientConfig);
    }   
}
```

But what was observed is the objects that get serialized, need to be on the classpath of the Hazelcast server as well(had to add the app JARs in the user-lib dir of the Hazelcast server otherwise it throws ClassNotFoundException) for the serialization to work Vs in the earlier approach that was not required.

I need help to understand why it is necessary and if there is a configuration or approach to avoid adding those application classes/JARs on the Hazelcast server side as we want to avoid doing that step in the deployment.

Since the hazelcast-wm approach does not require it, was wondering how it makes the serialization work without having to have those classes/JARs on the Hazelcast server classpath. If someone can please explain this, would be a great help. Thank you.